# Disable Clipboard Mapping and Remote Drive Mapping for RDP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop

Running a Windows Server 2016 instance (standalone) and I'm trying to figure out how to disable clipboard mapping and remote drive mapping while over remote desktop. I know there are options to disable this on the client side, but I want to enforce the restrictions on the server side. The goal is to prevent data exfiltration from this particular server.

And yes, I realize there are other methods, including screenshots. Which we've dealt with as best we can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deploy the following policies on the server to enforce this:

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Device and Resource Redirection\

=>  Do not allow Clipboard redirection

and

=> Do not allow drive redirection